# iOS 6 and GKAchievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios6, game-center

I'm making update for iOS game and facing next problem. I use this piece of code

```
[achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
{
   if (error != nil)
   {
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [storedDictionary setObject:achievement forKey:identifier];
     NSLog(@"Game Center: could not report achievement progress for %@, stored in defaults", identifier);
   }
}];
```

to report achievement progress (looks familiar, yeah? Yes, code from Apple tutorial). It works just fine on devices with iOS 5 or less, but nothing happens with iOS 6.

I've found clue, that I don't need to bother with saving postponed achievements in iOS 6, because it will do it for me, but [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW13) is still pretty clear about error handling. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mistyped the code for this question? It looks like the line:

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

should be:

NSUserDefaults *storedDictionary = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

Comment: Hm, don't think so. It could be typo if it was "default", but it's "defaults", so there is no mistake, I guess.